# Exclude Parent Id from Upward SOQL Query

Tags: soql

How do I exclude the Parent Id and additional metadata from this query in an apex class, and only return the Id of the lookup, Rate_Card__c?

```
List<Line_Item__c> rateCardId = ([SELECT Ad_Sale_Name__r.Rate_Card__c FROM Line_Item__c]);

System.debug(rateCardId);
```

My debug log is showing:

```
(Line_Item__c:{Ad_Sale_Name__c=a01M0000003AsthIAC, Id=a02M0000001xl6WIAQ})
```

I'd like to just pull: 
a02M0000001xl6WIAQ

Edit:

Should've double checked my output, I thought the Id was actually the Id of the Rate_Card, not the Line Item. Solved it by creating a formula field to display the Id of Rate Card at the end of the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing SELECT Ad_Sale_Name__r.Rate_Card__c FROM Line_Item__c you are explicitly selecting Ad_Sale_Name__r.Rate_Card__c  from the Line_item__c sobject.

You can either do

```
SELECT id FROM Line_Item__c (exclude the Ad_Sale_Name__r.Rate_Card__c) (or) 

for(line_item__c line: rateCardId){
system.debug(line.id);
}
```

Comment: that's the id for the `Line_Item__c`, not the `Rate_Card__c`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about what you're seeing in the debug statement.

```
Line_Item__c: {
    Ad_Sale_Name__c=a01M0000003AsthIAC, // <-- this is the Id of the Ad_Sale_Name__c lookup
    Id=a02M0000001xl6WIAQ // <-- this is the Id of the Line_Item__c record
}
```

Notice your `Rate_Card__c` id isn't shown.  That's because that id isn't present on the `Line_Item__c` record in the database.  That id is held on the `Ad_Sale_Name__c` table.  When you query the `Line_Item__c` table you get back a `Line_Item__c` SObject.

So, to get the rate card id you want, you need to access it through the relationship stored in memory in the SObject:

```
Line_Item__c lineItem = [SELECT Ad_Sale_Name__r.Rate_Card__c FROM Line_Item__c LIMIT 1];
Id rateCardId = lineItem.Ad_Sale_Name__r.Rate_Card__c;
```